# PHP/MYSQL match against query

Tags: mysql, match, against

I am trying to run a match against query and it is not working.  I created a full text index on the two fields.  But am getting sql error right before word 'relationship".  Here is sql:

```
"SELECT * FROM pages WHERE MATCH (shdescript,ldescript) AGAINST (romance, relationship)";
```

I have also tried just searching against shdescript and just searching against ldescript but get same error.  Also I've tried searchstring without spaces.  As far as I know, you are supposed to have the words of the searchstring separated by commas in parentheses.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add quotes around your search string.

Comment: That did it.  Related question: can I do a match against with a column from another table using a joined query?  Don't know how I would create index but it would help things a lot.  Can't accept answer yet

Comment: You should ask that as a separate question.

Comment: ok.  Just asked in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823202/mysql-match-against-query-two-tables

Answer (score 1):

```
"SELECT * FROM pages WHERE MATCH (shdescript,ldescript) AGAINST ('romance', 'relationship')";
```

Also make sure you protect yourself against the nasty SQL injection threat, read more [here](http://phptutorial.info/?mysql-real-escape-string).

Answer (score 1):

Try quoting your string (i.e 'romance' and 'relationship')

```
SELECT * FROM pages WHERE MATCH (shdescript,ldescript) AGAINST ('romance', 'relationship')
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `AGAINST` must be in quotes. From:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match

> AGAINST takes a string to search for, and an optional modifier that
>   indicates what type of search to perform. The search string must be a
>   literal string, not a variable or a column name.