# MYSQL match against query two tables

Tags: mysql, join, match, against

Is it possible to do a match against a query with two tables using a join?  The tricky part might be the index on the table but maybe there is a way.. sql is not my strong suit.  Many thanks.  I imagine it might be something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM 'pages' p
LEFT JOIN `tags` t
ON p.id = u.pageid
WHERE MATCH(p.shdescript,t.tag) AGAINST ('romance, relationship')
```

Many thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL full text search across multiple tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117005/mysql-full-text-search-across-multiple-tables)

Comment: Actually, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9951200/623041) to a different question is perhaps more helpful.

Comment: From those two questions, I'm getting you cannot use join but must use union.  Do you know if that's right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible, but you need to have text indexes.

```
mysql> alter table pages add fulltext index_text(shdescript);

mysql> alter table tags add fulltext index_text(tag);

SELECT * FROM 'pages' p
LEFT JOIN `tags` t
ON p.id = u.pageid
WHERE MATCH(p.shdescript,t.tag) AGAINST ('romance relationship')
```

I guess that's enough to work.

EDIT:

As of MySQL 5.6  the above fulltext search can be done on the MyISAM & InnoDB storage engines. On earlier MySQL versions only MyISAM tables supported fulltext indexes.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: This does not work in MySQL 8. I'm getting `Incorrect arguments to MATCH` error. All match columns must be in the same table: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2610897/2569676